# Spring security: activating csrf protection breaks other functionality

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, csrf

I'm using Spring Security 5.0.13 and I'd like to activate the csrf protection for the login page. I'm using the xml configuration, which I changed from

```
<http>
    ...
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
</http>
```

to

```
<bean id="csrfMatcher" class="org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher">
    <constructor-arg name="pattern" value="/j_spring_security_check"/>
    <constructor-arg name="httpMethod" value="POST"/>
</bean>
<csrf request-matcher-ref="csrfMatcher" />
```

However the  `j_spring_security_logout` endpoint now expects a `POST` request, whereas it used to accept a `GET` request. I know it would be better to have a `POST` request for the logout button, but I can't break this functionality as it's used elsewhere outside of my control.

How can I activate the csrf protection for the login page without affecting the logout url verb ?

Answer (score 0):

CSRF protection requires you to send a hidden input containing the CRSF attribute value for all requests that cause changes. That is what protects you - this CSRF attribute that is generated by your server and hence can't be faked by sending a request from some other place outside your website.

You can only send hidden inputs inside of forms with `post` requests therefore if you want csrf you will need to use `post`. Good news is - it is very easy, most template engines set everything for you automatically.

With Thymeleaf you don't even need to change anything, it generates this attribute in your post requests automatically.

With Mustache you would need to add following property:

```
spring.mustache.expose-request-attributes=true
```

And afterwards use following form:

```
<form id="logoutForm" method="POST" action="/logout">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{_csrf.token}}"/>
    <button type=submit>Logout</button>
</form>
```

As you can see it really is relatively easy, but you have to add the hidden crsf.token value to each post request, implementation depending on your template engine, and like I said with thymeleaf you wouldn't need to worry about it.

Comment: This unfortunately does not answer my question. As I said, I can't afford to switch to a POST method because the GET is used elsewhere. I would still like to be able to protect the login form though.

Comment: How can I explain to you that:
**a)** It is impossible to send information (csrf token) with GET
**b)** without this information there is no CSRF protection

You can't sit on two chairs,
you can't dance on 2 weddings,
you can't have your cake and eat it,
AND you can't have CSRF protection with only GET requests

Comment: You are not understanding the question. I have 2 endpoints, login and logout. Right now, none are secure. I want to secure the login endpoint, without affecting the verb of the logout endpoint. Please read the question again.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Spring Security reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html5/#servlet-considerations-csrf-logout), you can modify how Spring Security matches the `/logout` endpoint. By default, it looks for `POST /logout`, but you can configure it to look for `GET /logout` instead:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        http
            // ... other configs
            .logout(logout -> logout
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", "GET"))
            );
    }
}
```

There is no direct XML equivalent through the `<logout>` element, though you could declare your own `<bean>` of type [`LogoutFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutFilter.html) and [register it](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html5/#ns-custom-filters). Or [logging a ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/new/choose) might be an option to get it added to `<logout>`.